# Expected Value of a sequence and the probability of a sequence of random variables is 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of non-negative, integer-valued random variables.

Statement 1: if $E[X_n]\rightarrow0$ then $Pr\{X_n =0\} \rightarrow 1$.

Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of non-negative random variables.

Statement 2: if $E[Y_n]\rightarrow0$ then $Pr\{Y_n =0\} \rightarrow 1$.

Is the statement 1 true or false and why? Is the statement 2 true or false and why?

Just thinking logically, if I consider each $X_i$ in the sequence $X_n$ as an interval and the length of the interval decreases as $n\rightarrow0$, I think the statement 1 is true since and the statement 2 is false due to its continuous characteristic. However I am having trouble proving/disproving these statements mathematically. Would appreciate any hints or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) you can  use Cheychev's inequality: $P\{X_n \geq 1\} \leq EX_n \to 0$ so $P\{X_n=0\} \to 1$.

For 2) take any standard normal variable $X$ and define $Y_n=\frac {|X|} n$. Then $EY_n \to 0$ but $P\{Y_n=0\}=0$ for each $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for 1:  Can you show $P(X_n\ne0)=P(X_n\ge1)$?